# CakePHP 3.2 - Specify different datasource for session handler

Tags: php, mysql, session, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am having an issue specifying a different datasource to use in a custom session handler inside config/app.php. Here are the relevant bits:

**config/app.php**

```
<?php
return [
    ... ,
    'Datasources' => [
        'default' => [...],
        'test' => [...],
        'session' => [...]
    ],
    'Session' => [
        'defaults' => 'database',
        'ini' => ['session.cookie_domain' => '.example.com'],
        'handler' => [
            'engine' => 'CustomSessionHandler', // file and class name of custom handler
            'model' => 'sessions' // table name
        ]
    ]
];
```

`CustomSessionHandler.php` is a copy of the default `DatabaseSession.php` with a few customisations in the query building to work with our existing `sessions` table schema.

Right now, it's trying to use the 'default' datasource, and as you might guess, I'm trying to get it to use the 'session' datasource. However I can't find any information on how to do that.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The session handler only knows about the model, respectively the table class, and it shouldn't really know more than that.

So what you could do is configure that table class to use a non-default connection. If you don't have a concrete `SessionsTable` class yet, create one, and override `Table::defaultConnectionName()`, like

```
public static function defaultConnectionName()
{
    return 'session';
}
```

See also **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Table Objects > Configuring Connections](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#configuring-connections)**